# How to integrate Microsoft Graph API and fetch the object ID of a user from Microsoft Azure Active Directory in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to integrate Microsoft Active Directory and retrieve basic details like object id, name, photo, job Title and add them into my flutter app but I can't find any proper guide to do this so my question is how I can integrate Microsoft Graph API in my flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph API looks like it is a regular rest api so try something like this:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data